# SharePoint 2010 User Custom properties

Tags: 2010, powershell, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, custom-properties

Here is my question.  I saw in a previous post about getting when a user last logged in to SharePoint.

My understanding is that you can find this in the audit logs or you can add a custom property to a user profile.

How would I go about adding a date/time stamp to a user profile using custom properties?

I understand the mechanics of adding a custom property through the user profile service application.  Also, if I add this custom property, how I would go about reading it such as through Powershell?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.